# Force Bash to use 8 colors

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, ncurses

I made some animations and a game that are to be played in the terminal and they rely on the terminal only having 8 colors available. When I run them on a Terminal that has 16 colors available (particularly obvious when you run neofetch and see the colors available) they do not render properly at all.

Is there a quick and dirty way to force a linux terminal to use only 8 colors?

Edit: The problem may also be that I was using an older version of ncurses on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS when I made these programs. I am attempting to get them to look right on a distro with an up-to-date version of the library. For anyone interested in attempting to answer the question I originally posed I'll still accept anything that demonstrates ways to force gnome-terminal to revert to 8-color mode if that's even possible.

Edit: The problem was related to my frequent use of standend() to revert the drawing functions back to white on black text. For some reason this was not doing what I expected it to do on some distros. By explictly telling it to attron() a color pair that was defined explictly as black and white I solved the problem. This is a hacky and hard-coded solution that stems from my abusing the ncurses library in a hard-coded way. Consider this solved, although I'd be interested in some digestible resources on programming with raw escape sequences for the future to better understand this problem.

Comment: Set `TERM=xterm`?

Comment: more likely you're trying to use some hardcoded script, which ignores `TERM` (or makes  silly assumptions, such as "vt100s do color").

Comment: Without seeing the scripts, one can only guess.  The terminal description for "xterm" says the terminal only supports the standard ANSI 8 colors, but a program can ignore that, doing whatever the terminal actually supports.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to my frequent use of standend() to revert the drawing functions back to white on black text. For some reason this was not doing what I expected it to do on some distros. By explictly telling it to attron() a color pair that was defined explictly as black and white I solved the problem. This is a hacky and hard-coded solution that stems from my abusing the ncurses library in a hard-coded way.